# Incremental data mapping

Tags: c++11, bigdata, transformation

How can we efficiently load the data from an incremental CSV file without reading the whole file repetitively?

I have used the timestamp information from the given file to load the data in every 5 minutes but in case the timestamp information is not available how can we make it work?

Comment: Remember where you were up to in the file ( save in another the file the offset). Then next time seek to that point and start reading, then re as ave end poinr

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.